# Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler i n thread "Thread-9"

Tags: installation, startup

I just installed spring-tool-suite-3.7.0.RELEASE-e4.5-win32-x86_64
I ran sts-bundle\sts-3.7.0.RELEASE\STS.exe
Then I ran sts-bundle\sts-3.7.0.RELEASE\exclepsec.exe

I got an out of memory.
Error at start up in the traces:
**

```
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration
 bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry aft
er the state location is initialized.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: C:\Users\sBriet\Docu
ments\workspace-sts-3.7.0.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.logback.con
figuration\logback.1.6.1.20150625-2338.xml
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://935.fwk1294950326:1/org/slf4j/impl/Sta
ticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://935.fwk1294950326:2/org/slf4j/impl/Sta
ticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorSta
ticBinder]
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
Error while informing user about event loop exception:
Exception in thread "Thread-11"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler i
n thread "Thread-11"
Error while informing user about event loop exception:
```

**

I have increase the memory available in the STS.ini file :
**

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms256m
-Xmx1536m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xverify:none
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
```

**

How can I get rid of this issue?
First I do not have to click anything in the gui, the out of memory comes automatically after a 30s. The solution suggested "http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings" does not provide any solution for this case.

Comment: C:\Users\sBriet>java -version
java version "1.7.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.1-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: C:\Users\sBriet>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03

Comment: the name of the eclipse file that I ran is : sts-bundle\sts-3.7.0.RELEASE\eclipsec.exe

Comment: I removed the jar files:
org.slf4j.api_1.7.2.v20121108-1250.jar and 
org.slf4j.impl.log4j12_1.7.2.v20131105-2200.jar 
so now I can startup and got the message flow:
Creating instance 'base-instance' ...
As soon as I get to create a basic java program I get the messages in log windows:
`Exception in thread "Java indexing"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler i
n thread "Java indexing"
Error while logging event loop exception:
Error while logging event loop exception:`
and I get blocked at that point

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
You must use jdk 8 to solve this. I could not get it working with jdk 7!

I ran (in a large command window 150x30 with more than 1000 lines) :

> eclipsec.exe -consoleLog

I get the errors below (reported by other people).

```
> C:\sts-bundle\sts-3.7.0.RELEASE>eclipsec.exe -consoleLog
!SESSION 2015-08-07 15:48:30.291 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=3.7.0.201506290652-RELEASE-e45
java.version=1.7.0_03
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.fx.core 4 0 2015-08-07 15:48:37.928
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.fx.core [412]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jdt.annotation; bundle-version="2.0.100.v20150311-1658"
   org.eclipse.jdt.annotation [421]
     Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

!ENTRY org.eclipse.fx.osgi.util 4 0 2015-08-07 15:48:37.999
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR

Answer (score 0):

Get this problem with ZendStudio (which is base on Eclispe)

I deleted the directory `jre` located in the ZendStudio directory racine and zend did start properly without error (it will use the jre install in your machine, true for Linux don't know about other OS)